# Switching to metric / Celsius in Ubuntu touch

Tags: locale

I just bought a BQ with Ubuntu and I am trying to figure out how to configure it.

I am in Ireland so my main language is English, we use the metric system and Celsius. How can I set up the nearby and weather apps to use the correct measurement systems for Ireland.

Also I have found that I get UK options for domain suffixes in the onscreen keyboard instead of ie and eu. That is not such a big deal though.

Comment: Maybe you have _English (US)_ as the selected language. Try to change it in System Settings to e.g. _English (UK)_.

Comment: No, I had English (Ireland) but I switched to English (Denmark) this morning but I still get same results.

Comment: I don't want English uk, I am Irish

Comment: Sorry; forgot that there is an English (Ireland) locale. Anyway, Both the English (Ireland) and English (Denmark) locales have the metric system, so apparently this is not locale dependent.

Comment: If it is not locale dependent I would have thought there would be a setting to change it. I only see options to switch off feeds.

Comment: I will try to track down this apps authors and open a bug report.

Comment: There is an open bug on the topic: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1547981